# How can I find all files in a folder with a certain text string and an extension?

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I am using OS X.

I need to find files in a directory with the `.php` extension and the string `41` somewhere in the file's contents.

I tried using `grep`.

```
grep -R 41 *.php
```

This however only seemed to find files in the CWD and not in sub directories.

I also tried messing with `find`.

I wasn't able to figure this out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `41` needs to be in the file name, or its content?

Comment: @Daniel In the contents, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: it does that because you told it to only search all files ending in php in the CWD - mind the expansion precedence...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need both.

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec grep -q 41 {} \; -print
```

Comment: +1 Ignacio. Is it possible for it show the excerpt of the file where it found the substring, like `grep` normally does? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Just remove `-q` and the `-print` predicate.

Comment: Thank you. I really need to learn more about these things...

Comment: As you do, you'll learn why `find . -name '*.php' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 fgrep 41 --` is the next thing that people will suggest to you.

Comment: No need for `xargs`; BSD find understands `-exec ... +`.

Comment: that's a workaround, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

in order for grep to work recursively, the argument to grep needs to include the directories it's expected to recurse.

looking at the following files

```
shiny:t fl$ find .
.
./evenmore
./evenmore/foo.php
./evenmore/inhere.php
./evenmore/no41in.php
./foo.php
./inhere.php
./morestuff
./morestuff/foo.php
./morestuff/inhere.php
./morestuff/no41in.php
./no41in.php
./stuff
./stuff/no41in.php
```

this does not work:

```
shiny:t fl$ grep -r 41 *.php
foo.php:41
inhere.php:41
```

because after path name expansion is done, the shell has processed the asterisk and the command line is now

```
shiny:t fl$ set -x
shiny:t fl$ grep -r 41 *.php
+ grep -r 41 foo.php inhere.php no41in.php
foo.php:41
inhere.php:41
```

there is no directory to descend in in the argument handed to grep. This however will descend in all directories present:

```
shiny:t fl$ grep -r 41 .
./evenmore/foo.php:41
./evenmore/inhere.php:41
./foo.php:41
./inhere.php:41
./morestuff/foo.php:41
./morestuff/inhere.php:41
```

whether that also processes dot-directories is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com) you can do `ack 41 --php`.

`ack` is like `grep` with built-in highlighting and line numbering and it's designed for searching source code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use

```
grep 41 **/*.php
```

and it worked.